# How to filter data in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, filter

I'm building advertisement service in Flask and want to let users filter adverts by category but dont know how to do that in python and flask.

For example, we have following Advert form:

```
class AdvertForm(FlaskForm):
    title = StringField('Title', validators=[DataRequired()])
    content = TextAreaField('Content', validators=[DataRequired()])
    category = SelectField('Caterogry', validators=[DataRequired()], choices=[('car','Car'), ('work','Work'), ('sport','Sport')])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

And following html:

```
  <div class="categories">
    <div class="category-item">
      <a href="">Cars</a>
    </div>
    <div class="category-item">
      <a href="">Work</a>
    </div>
    <div class="category-item">
      <a href="">Sport</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And when user clicks on *Cars* item in HTML I want to make subpage *127.0.0.1:5000/cars* and display only adverts which have car category

Comment: Instead of posting a link to all of your code, make a short example of the exact problem you are trying to solve and directly post that code in your question. that way people in the future that look at this will be able to see the code even if your link dies.

Comment: Sorry, its my first post here, now question is edited

Answer (score 0):

You could capture the category selected by the user and send it back to your Python function. Then, depending on the selection, route the user to the appropriate sub-page.

```
@app.route('/mainpage', methods=['GET','POST'])
def mainpage():
    form = AdvertForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        selectedCategory = request.form['category']
        nextPage = selectedCategory + ".html"
        return render_template(nextPage)
    return render_template('mainpage.html', form=form)
```

In the example above, if the users chooses Car and clicks Submit, they will be routed to `http://localhost:5000/car.html`. If they choose Work, they will be routed to `http://localhost:5000/work.html`. I'm sure you get the idea.